# Get trough json parse user name and id from facebook graph

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am new with facebook api. I tried multiply tutorials but nothing works out for me...
I am using api level 10, platform 2.3.3, the connections works fine, but when i log out and open the application again it should show me the welcome text with me name but instead
the application crash...

The Code:

```
package com.example.kamehameha;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseObject;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook fb;
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    TextView welcome;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String APP_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

        welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);

        sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String at = sp.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if(at != null){
            fb.setAccessToken(at);
        }
        if(expires != 0){
            fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        getName();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getName(){

        JSONObject obj = null;
        welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);

        if(fb.isSessionValid()){            

            try {
                String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
                String name = obj.optString("name");
                welcome.setText("Welcome"+name);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }else{
            fb.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fbError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });         
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

What I get in logcat:

```
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kamehameha/com.example.kamehameha.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:219)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:732)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.example.kamehameha.MainActivity.getName(MainActivity.java:71)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at com.example.kamehameha.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
02-05 01:10:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(30114):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the new Android Facebook SDK which is 3.0 this is much more easier to use than the one you are using and i think it is deprecated